# 404 vs 200 for relative entities, RESTful

Tags: api, rest, http

What status code is more appropriate for a case when relation is not existing?

For instance, `/articles/1/comments/4`, with this call you will get `commentID` 4 from `articleID` 1. But what if `commentID` 4 not exists in this relation, what should API returned, `404` or `200` ?

**EDIT**: Let me clarify what do I meant.

The thing is, you can interpret `404` like resource not exists from another point of view, for instance: `/articles/1/builders/3`. You don't have such route at all in your application! Your application does have handler for such url completely. But `/articles/1/comments/4`. You have such route in app, you have handler (controller). And yeah, I know that this url reflect relationship between comments and articles, and this is why it is tricky. Because comment with `ID` 4 might exists in your `DB` even if it does not belong to article. Then if you have such route in application you may say that from http protocol point of view you have such resource, but based on your application logic, you may say that such comment not belongs to specified article.

Comment: Why would you return 200? (And why do we get 20 _"What HTTP status code or verb to use in $RESTy situation"_ per day, is there still no definitive guide out there for this?)

Comment: And with what content?

Answer (score 4):

It should be `404` (of course). You requested for a particular resource with ID equal to 4 and did not find it.

Comment: I know, but it's very tricky situation, cause 404 means that resource not exists, but it's exist! and even such comment ID is exist it's just not belongs to specified article. For instance, if you request `articles/1/comment/4` yeah this is 404 cause we don't have such route at all. SO I'm trying to say if you look on api from different view (transport, application), you might interpret status codes differently.

Comment: It should still return `404` in that case but `/comments/4` should return 200 along with the article. Nothing is tricky here, trust me.

Comment: just try to see dark side. Hope you don't think that I don't know what are you speaking about :) I understand in this area enough. Just suddenly this idea came in my mind as an alternative sight.

Comment: To eliminate such behavior you may instead of using commentID you can use and ID of relation between a comment and an article. In such relation does not exists, it's for sure, 404 and may be easier to understand.

Comment: @user1016265, after you edited the question I still suggest to use 404 in such cases.